# my app is showing twice in the software centre?

Tags: software-center, application-development

I have published an application in the software center by uploading `dsc` and `tar.gz` in an archive.

In the software center it is showing twice one with my application icon and one  with default icon. how to solve this?

Comment: What is the application name? And how have you installed it on your own system?

Answer (score -1):

actually The problem is that in the Ubuntu we have application files and its .Desktop file. so when you search both the application file and .Desktop file of your application(for which you have not given any Icon) both are listing and neither one has `NoDisplay=true` set. I guess the desktop file for the home folder should have NoDisplay set to true for your application. If you set it to false then it wont come again.

and one more thing , your issue is also bug in 12.04 but in 13.04.

Answer (score -1):

Alvar  are you on 64bit.  If so you may find that one is the 64bit deb and the other is the 32bit binary.  If this is the case the only thing you can do is provide Developer Portal with  very specific 32 and 64bit debs.  Other wise just leave it as is.  People by default will click on the one with the image.